# Why can't I search maven projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm using the m2Eclipse plugin (http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) to handle maven modules in eclipse.  After enabling a project for dependency management and for nested modules, I can no longer do a 'File Search' over the project.  The search finishes instantly with the search window display "0 matches in empty scope".

Any ideas how I can make search work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the plugin marks any non java folder as 'derived', which is why it gets ignored by the search.  Right clicking on the non java folders and deselecting the check box fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to @slashnick’s answer:

In the “File Search” dialog of Eclipse you can also use the checkbox “Consider derived resources” to search those “derived” resources. This may be more convenient if you don’t want to change the properties of multiple resources just for a search.